# How do I remove accounts from my analytics dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics

How do I remove accounts from my analytics dashboard where other admins have deleted me from the profile? The account appears on the list with no data and now discernible way to remove it.

Comment: I see that in the new version of analytics the sites are not displaying, which is great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a [known bug in Google Analytics.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=6544da48052b0bb1&hl=en&start=80) In short, if a user gives you guest access to a website in their Analytics account, then removes that site from their account to stop tracking it without first removing you as an admin user, you're stuck with a ghost reference to their site.

You could try contacting Google from the [AdWords email support page.](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/request.py?display=categories) Choose "Google Analytics, Conversion Tracking, AdWords Editor", then "Google Analytics", then "I'm experiencing a technical issue when using my account" and finally "Email AdWords Support".

Comment: +1 ... but don't get your hopes up - I've gone through this process and none of the profiles in question have been removed yet. Unless they're still working through a three or four year backlog, it would not seem as though Google is prioritizing these requests ...

Comment: Yes, it looks like it is definitely a bug. I found loads of threads on the Google support forums referring to the same issue and nothing in the way of a formal response from Google. That said, I see that the offending sites do not appear in the list of my sites in the new version of analytics which you can toggle to at the moment. So it looks like the problem is about to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

**Just wait...**

This happened to me. Eventually, the account was just removed from my dashboard. I did add another account around the same time, but I don't think it was related.

---

Otherwise, you can ask the current admin to temporarily add you as a user (admin?) so you can remove the analytics account from your dashboard.